# Apache Kafka topic data in HDFS format

Tags: apache-kafka

Currently i installed kafka into linux and created **topic** and published message to it and it saves data in the folder **/tmp/kafka-logs/topicname-0**, as i checked the local file system type is **xfs**, is there any way kafka can save data in the format of **HDFS** file system type, if yes help me with configuration or steps.

Comment: You should seriously consider not having your Kafka storage in the /tmp folder

Answer (score 1):

Kafka runs on top of a local filesystem. It cannot be run on HDFS. If you want to move data from Kafka into HDFS, one option is using a connector to push the data to HDFS https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html

Comment: Thanks dawsaw, at least can we avoid data store into local file system and can directly push to HDFS?

Comment: Kafka stores data at least for some amount of time (configurable) in a local filesystem. It's considered one of the benefits. If you don't want the data stored locally at all, you might consider just making a point to point connection between whatever system the data is coming from and HDFS. Flume with a memory channel comes to mind as an option.

Comment: Thanks dawsaw, also could you please help me how i can save data in .log file only binary data.